# The set of all strings that do not contain the substring aba and bbb over alphabet { a,b,c }

Tags: regex

I have spent alot of time on this one and I can't solve this.
what is the regular expression for all strings that do not contain the substring aba and bbb over alphabet { a,b,c }

Comment: what does mean *over alphabet { a,b,c }* ?

Comment: over alphabet means that all the chars in {} are all the chars that you can use, i.e you can only make word from a,b and c.

Comment: Why don't you post the list of strings you talk about. You could even show something you've tried since you've _spent a lot of time on this one_.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
^(?:(?!aba|bbb)[abc])*$
```

The pattern `(?!aba|bbb)[abc]` matches any `a`, `b` or `c` that is not the start of `aba` or `bbb`. So we can simply repeat it zero or more times using `*`.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with:

```
^(?!(?:aba|bbb)$)[abc]$
```

meaning:
"aba|bbb" matches one of both strings exactly
"(?:...)" grouping (non-capturing)
"(?:...)$" matches at end of line
"(?!...)" negative lookahead: if string does not contain pattern which follows, use "[abc]$" to match any combination of a,b,c